# How do I import another component but not have that other element render to a div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want the Torrent component to render without having that Torrent render to a DOM element. how do i do it?

I want my Torrent Table Component to be comprised of Torrent Components, based on what my API feeds back to me. However I'm getting a problem where it doesn't render on the website since ReactDOM.render() is not binding the component to a DOM element.

```
class TorrentTable extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            torrents : []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
        let torrent_string = window.location.href.split("/")[4];
        console.log(window.location.href);

        fetch(`api/get/${torrent_string}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({
                torrents : data
            })
        });

    }

    render()
    {

        return(
            <table className="table" style={{ width : "100%"}}>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">

                        </th>

                        <th scope="col">
                            Torrent Name
                        </th>

                        <th scope="col">
                            Magnet
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        this.state.torrents.map(torrent => {
                            <Torrent name={torrent.title} magnet={torrent.magnet} image={torrent.image_url}/>
                        })
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TorrentTable />, document.getElementById("torrent_table"));
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `ReactDOM.render` renders the `TorrentTable` inside the `document.getElementById("torrent_table")` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to render the root of your application with ReactDOM.render().

I think the problem is that you aren't returning the  component from within your map statement.

Either add a return statement like this.

```
this.state.torrents.map(torrent => {
    return <Torrent name={torrent.title} magnet={torrent.magnet} image={torrent.image_url}/>
})
```

Or return it directly like this.

```
this.state.torrents.map(torrent => (
    <Torrent name={torrent.title} magnet={torrent.magnet} image={torrent.image_url}/>
))
```